# How to make a Chai custom assertion fail?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

This minimal example custom chai assertion should fail. It does not. What is missing to make it fail?

```
const chai = require('chai');

chai.Assertion.addMethod('test1', function() {
    this.assert(
        false,
        "Failed",
        "Failed",
        "foo",
        "bar"
    );
});

chai.expect({}).to.be.test1;
```

Comment: What do you get when you add `true` as the sixth argument to `this.assert()`?

Comment: @RandyCasburn stil passes no difference.

Comment: `.to.be.test1` is invalid syntax. What is `test1` and what are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks @alfasin. Your comment led me to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

test1 must be called. As in:
`chai.expect({}).to.be.test1();`